# How to check whether a textbox is placed inside a panel using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am having a `TextBox` and an `ImageButton` within an `ASP:Panel`. I have set DefaultButton property to the panel. When I focus on the `TextBox` and press the enter key, the server side click event of `ImageButton` should be fired. For that, I need to check a condition in script (i.e) whether the textbox is placed inside the panel and the panel has `DefaultButton` property, so that I can call the server side event on enter press. So, can anyone please let me know how to check whether the `TextBox` is placed inside a `Panel` using script??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Neither `<textbox>` nor `<panel>` are valid HTML elements, you might want to elaborate on your question.

Comment: @Zeta Just pulling the given information together, I'd assumed (dangerous, I know) that this is ASP.NET.

Comment: @GrantThomas: This is a quite dangerous assumption. Do you have any proofs? (j/k as I don't know anything about ASP.NET, but it's good to know that it has such facilities).

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to - if this is ASP.NET you're talking about, as I assume - the click event handler will only be executed when *that* button is pressed. If a postback occurs due to another button on the form being pressed then the event handler associated with that button will be executed, and not the other one in question.

If you're having particular difficulty with this then perhaps you could explain precisely what the problem is.

Comment: +1 very true, and I've always assumed this was the main purpose of the `DefaultButton` property, a workaround for WebForms as they only have 1 form.

Answer (score 0):

You can't check server attributes from client side. You should tell us what you really want to do and maybe we could give you another approach.